# How to adjust the View size using onMeasue()

Tags: java, android, layout

I would like to adjust the View size using onMeasue().
Parent width and height are 1920 and 1080, respectively.

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int parentViewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int parentViewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            
    super.onMeasure(
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parentViewWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parentViewHeight-200, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    }
```

If I run the above code, the result is like the following (Case #1). However, I would like to make the view like Case #2. Please let me know how to do it. Thanks a lot in advance.

[see the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3UOx.png)

Comment: is there any reason why you're trying to do this instead of providing a bottom margin layout parameter?

Comment: Because there are buttons on the top margin.

Comment: Can you add the layout xml file from which you are inflating the view?